# Transpose a Pandas dataframe around a column with many repeated entries

Tags: pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have created a data frame that has a dozen attributes (e.g. P/E, P/B) for a set of 300 stocks at the end of each month for 10 years. The dataframe is initially indexed by month (so there are 300 observations in each month) and then by stock ticker (so that there are 400 observations associated with each ticker).  My dataframe has  about 12 columns and 120,000 rows.

I now want to transpose the dataframe so that the columns are the stock tickers, i.e. to have about 300 columns, one per stock. I would like the date to continue to be associated with each row, so that I have about 4,800 rows associated with each ticker in a column (12 variables x 400 observations).

```
#Sort the dataframe, first by ticker and then by date, then write to Excel
DF.sort_values(by=['Date', 'ticker'], inplace=True)
DF.to_excel(outPath + outFn1)

#Now make ticker the index and sort by ticker and date 
DF = DF.reset_index().set_index('ticker')
DF.sort_values(by=['ticker', 'Date'], inplace=True)
DF.to_excel(outPath + outFn2)

#Now transpose the dataframe
DF = DF.reset_index().set_index('Date')
DF = DF.transpose()
DF.to_excel(outPath + outFn3)
```

Unfortunately, when I do the last df.transpose(), I get 120,000 columns and only 12 rows – the 300 tickers and 400 months are transformed into 120,000 columns, with the month (the index) being displayed in the first row! Is there a way to have only 300 columns (one per ticker) and 4,800 rows (one per month per variable)?

Many thanks in advance for your assistance

Thomas Philips

Comment: can you show us an example of the data?

Comment: Date cusip ticker BP PM12M1M
1986-12-31 00:00:00 037833100 AAPL 0.2736468 0.8181818
1987-01-31 00:00:00 037833100 AAPL 0.1996882 0.7513514
1987-02-28 00:00:00 037833100 AAPL 0.158324 1.22

Comment: Date cusip ticker BP PM12M1M
    1986-12-31 00:00:00 037833100 AAPL 0.2736468 0.8181818
    1987-01-31 00:00:00 037833100 AAPL 0.1996882 0.7513514
    1987-02-28 00:00:00 037833100 AAPL 0.158324 1.22

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `DataFrame` - `data` that looks like this:

```
Feature              0         1    ...            6         7
Month Ticker                        ...                       
0     A       0.584049  0.701758    ...     0.724876  0.091812
      B       0.546022  0.554775    ...     0.381720  0.014467
      C       0.166254  0.810845    ...     0.848234  0.078745
      D       0.164278  0.409916    ...     0.472850  0.836136
      E       0.196801  0.556134    ...     0.451976  0.339668
1     A       0.336286  0.971672    ...     0.710570  0.344017
      B       0.449617  0.052413    ...     0.878496  0.404431
      C       0.383405  0.282608    ...     0.972533  0.957979
      D       0.328034  0.068577    ...     0.365409  0.158591
      E       0.846107  0.923831    ...     0.839615  0.890490
2     A       0.054455  0.427796    ...     0.528548  0.568229
      B       0.953295  0.567187    ...     0.035515  0.467428
      C       0.155837  0.810630    ...     0.512707  0.991404
      D       0.626261  0.268854    ...     0.919632  0.630014
      E       0.978789  0.578045    ...     0.155516  0.538323
3     A       0.641031  0.733028    ...     0.911317  0.210537
      B       0.341537  0.682774    ...     0.778101  0.017675
      C       0.574298  0.707269    ...     0.967428  0.319638
      D       0.577600  0.563917    ...     0.831466  0.053403
      E       0.732570  0.475240    ...     0.696523  0.417793
```

> **EDIT:** I've Just realized there is a much more simple way to do it.
>
> ```
> data.reset_index().set_index('Month').groupby('Month').apply(lambda g: g.set_index('Ticker').T)
> ```
>
> In terms of performance both solutions are similar. Although I was testing on a small data set. I assume that on larger ones `stack` might hurt.

First Stack it and reindex:

```
stacked = data.stack().to_frame().reset_index().set_index(['Month', 'Feature'])
```

And now we are ready to pivot:

```
stacked.pivot(index=stacked.index, columns='Ticker')[0]
```

The result will look like this:

```
Ticker                A         B         C         D         E
Month Feature                                                  
0     0        0.584049  0.546022  0.166254  0.164278  0.196801
      1        0.701758  0.554775  0.810845  0.409916  0.556134
      2        0.746143  0.996657  0.843376  0.739536  0.518822
      3        0.191602  0.274246  0.207361  0.739565  0.980208
      4        0.173600  0.095523  0.184685  0.869971  0.004018
      5        0.891771  0.508821  0.178942  0.423447  0.804024
      6        0.724876  0.381720  0.848234  0.472850  0.451976
      7        0.091812  0.014467  0.078745  0.836136  0.339668
1     0        0.336286  0.449617  0.383405  0.328034  0.846107
      1        0.971672  0.052413  0.282608  0.068577  0.923831
      2        0.769480  0.651071  0.322606  0.811118  0.321575
      3        0.527988  0.709826  0.254327  0.099533  0.117720
      4        0.240174  0.768326  0.689877  0.587520  0.162302
      5        0.287952  0.636137  0.557708  0.212823  0.832591
      6        0.710570  0.878496  0.972533  0.365409  0.839615
      7        0.344017  0.404431  0.957979  0.158591  0.890490
2     0        0.054455  0.953295  0.155837  0.626261  0.978789
      1        0.427796  0.567187  0.810630  0.268854  0.578045
      2        0.938299  0.821334  0.500624  0.037103  0.753389
      3        0.671038  0.202686  0.958819  0.793337  0.598762
      4        0.458506  0.371354  0.751473  0.624051  0.157371
      5        0.467098  0.884003  0.747713  0.771846  0.484238
      6        0.528548  0.035515  0.512707  0.919632  0.155516
      7        0.568229  0.467428  0.991404  0.630014  0.538323
3     0        0.641031  0.341537  0.574298  0.577600  0.732570
      1        0.733028  0.682774  0.707269  0.563917  0.475240
      2        0.847406  0.920411  0.017330  0.308168  0.311288
      3        0.882707  0.252812  0.663594  0.742554  0.648782
      4        0.134776  0.539955  0.825222  0.227707  0.215726
      5        0.291174  0.111133  0.645823  0.676221  0.753326
      6        0.911317  0.778101  0.967428  0.831466  0.696523
      7        0.210537  0.017675  0.319638  0.053403  0.417793
```

Comment: It seems like we are headed in the right direction but something is not yet right. If I type
`combinedDF.head()`

Comment: It seems we are headed in the right direction but are not yet there fully. If I type
`combinedDF.head()`

I get a simple data frame with columns Date (the index), ticker, Feature0, Feature1, Feature 2,....

And if I type
`combinedDF.stack().to_frame().reset_index().set_index('Date')`
I get three columns: Date: level_1 and 0

But if I now type 
`stacked.pivot(columns = 'ticker')`, 
I get a KeyError, so I'm not sure what is going on. I'm told there's an R equivalent:
`tapply(dat$Feature, list(dat$Date,dat$ticker),I)`
so we're likely on the right track, but not home as yet.

Comment: Oddly enough, the simple solution
`data.reset_index().set_index('Month').groupby('Month').apply(lambda g: g.set_index('Ticker').T)`
does work - thank you very much! I must confess that I don't fully understand its working, but  will work on it. I have done one last step in Excel - add the month to every line. Is there a way to do this in Python to obviate the need for any further processing in Excel?

Comment: You can use `reset_index`.